# top yAxis overlaps the bottom one

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I created a chart with two yAxis, one above another. It looks ok when autoscale is on. But when I set min and max, top yAxis overlaps the bottom one.

```
 chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        alignTicks: false
    },

    yAxis: [{
        height: 200,
        lineWidth: 2,
        min:150
    }, {
        top: 300,
        height: 100,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2,
        max:140
    }],
    series: [{
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9] 
    }]
});
```

Example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yDj62/2/
How can I truncate top yAxis with its borders?

Comment: This is known issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1387

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `solved` in up-to-date version of Highstock.

http://jsfiddle.net/yDj62/2/